# Spring-boot-aop project cannot create PointCut (Pointcut is not wellformed exception)

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

> trying to build simple aop project
>
> > error is Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting >>>'(' at character position 0
> >
> > > > p1
> > > >
> > > > > all imports and packages are correct i double checked.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TxService {

@Pointcut("execution(public void com.boot.aop.dao.EmployeeDao.saveEmployee())")
public void p1() {
    
}
        
@Before("p1")
public void beginTx() {  // advice
        
    System.out.println("Transaction is started");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the pointcut is not well-formed. To be more precise, the pointcut reference is not. The actual pointcut looks OK. Please use:

```java
@Before("p1()")
```

Do not forget the parentheses!